# Submit Form Only When Checkbox is Checked

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox, submit

For a similar to the following example code, how can I do the following when the user hits submit, using Jquery
1) check if the checkbox is checked.
 -If yes, submit the form.
 - If not, show an alert "Please check the box before submitting the form", cancel form submission.
2) After, when the checkbox is checked form can be submitted.

```html
<html>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chbox" id="chbox">Check this box before submission 
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
  </html>
```

Comment: please update with the code for form submit.

Comment: `$('#chbox').is(':checked')` will return true checkbox is checked else false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chbox" id="chbox">Check this box before submission
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        $("#myForm").on('submit', function ()
        {
            if (document.getElementById("chbox").checked)
            {
                $("#myForm").submit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Please check the box before submitting the form');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add **required** attribute to the checkbox. I would recommend that you wrap the text in a label as well.

```
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="chbox" id="chbox" required>Check this box before submission </label>
```